# Sed script that removes specific lines in `seq` output

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file to process with `sed` but I am not quite familiar with the commands with capital letters used for multi-line patterns. I use `seq` to test the script and I have converted it to the problem described below. The `sed` script and expected output are also attached. I believe the script can be written in a much better way but I am not sure how to do it.

#### Problem description:

> Filter the output of `seq $m`, where `$m` is a given integer. removing the \$n^{\rm th}\$ line if either \$n-2\$, \$n-1\$, \$n\$, or \$n+1\$ contains the digit \$7\$.

Sed script (together with the `seq` pipe, note this is `GNU sed`):

```
seq "$m"|sed ':c N;N;N;:a N;s/.*\n.*7.*\n.*\n.*\n//g;tc;P;s/^[^\n]*\n//g;ba;'
```

I believe setting two labels (`a` and `c`) is not necessary.

**Edit**: There seems to be a nicer alternative, based on the answer to [Delete 5 Lines Before and 6 Liens After Pattern Match Using `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046210/how-to-delete-5-lines-before-and-6-lines-after-pattern-match-using-sed), as follows,

```
seq "$m"|sed 'N;/7/!{P;D};:b N;s/\n/&/3;Tb;d'
```

This avoids writing out a lot of `N;` and `\n`'s explicitly. Still I believe it can be improved.

Sample output for `m=100`

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
11
12
13
14
15
20
21
22
23
24
25
30
31
32
33
34
35
40
41
42
43
44
45
50
51
52
53
54
55
60
61
62
63
64
65
82
83
84
85
90
91
92
93
94
95
100
```

Related: [Extension of Game of Sevens Challenge at CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154147/extension-of-the-game-of-sevens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
N;/7/!{P;D}
```

Nice job there, this very concisely (and clearly) allows you to capture both lines \$n\$ and \$n+1\$.

```
:b N;s/\n/&/3;Tb;d
```

Now the loop that follows it is mostly redundant. You are essentially appending lines of input until you are left with \$4\$ lines in total. You already have \$2\$ in your pattern space and need \$2\$ more, i.e. lines \$n-1\$ and \$n-2\$, which can simply be expressed in `N;N` followed by a `d`.